# mysql self join query along with mapping table

Tags: mysql, join

I have MySql database, with a table containing columns:

```
table_1 {
  id (int),
  parameter (varchar),
  value (double)
}
```

Now parameter can have 2 different values - steps & distance.

I have one more mapping table_2 which maps steps from table_1 to corresponding distance in table_1.

So table_2 just stores two ids of table_1 and its schema is

```
table_2 {
  table_1_steps_id (int),
  table_1_distance_id(int)
}
```

What will be the query to get steps and corresponding distance in one resultset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way to get steps and distance would be this:

```
SELECT
  ts.value as steps,
  td.value as distance
FROM
  table_2 LEFT JOIN table_1 ts
  ON table_2.table_1_steps_id = ts.id AND ts.parameter='steps'
  LEFT JOIN table_1 td
  ON table_2.table_1_distance_id = td.id AND td.parameter='distance'
```

Comment: thanks for that, I tried it but its giving long list of null  values and result at the end, how can i eliminate those nulls?

Comment: I changed LEFT JOIN to just "join" (equi join i suppose) and eliminated null values

Comment: @comeOnGetIt it could be fine to use a JOIN instead of a LEFT JOIN, the left join will return null values because for example `table_2.table_1_steps_id=4` but you don't have a correlated value in table_1 with `id=4,parameter='steps'` so the join won't succeed. Are you sure you want to skip those rows? You might have to investigate why you are missing those values

Comment: got it, however, in my case, the column table_2.table_1_steps_id is ALWAYS subset of the column table_1.id, so there is no chance by which table_2.table_1_steps_id=xyz and xyz does not exist in table_1.id, so only JOIN should be safe bet right ?

Comment: @comeOnGetIt i think it's better to investigate...if you get null values it means that xyz does not exist, or it exists but not with parameter='step'. I think you should `SELECT table_1_steps_id, table_1_distance_id, ... WHERE ts.value IS NULL OR td.value IS NULL` and see which values are not present and why